# Auto complete user's response C

Tags: c, fgets

Is there a way to auto complete a user's response? For example, I have a prompt for the user to select from a choice of settings. They can change it at any time but I want it to automatically fill in the current setting so that they only have to press enter if they want that particular setting. Alternatively, they can backspace and enter their own setting if they want.

My abridged code:

```
char response[10] = "Random";

printf("Enter your setting: ");

//Need code here to auto fill

fgetsf(response, sizeof(response), stdin);
```

Desired output:

Enter your setting: Random

The cursor would be right after Random waiting for the user to press enter or backspace to fill in their own setting.

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine you'll want to use `getchar()` and some terminal escapes. And/or curses.

Comment: Perhaps [Readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) can help you with this.

Comment: Common idiom in Unix programs is to display the default option in brackets and treat the empty input as choosing default, e.g.: `printf("Enter your setting [Random]: "); fgets(response, sizeof(response), stdin); if(*response=='\n' || !*response){ strcpy(response, "Random"); }`

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider using GNU readline library, where you could pre-define options and get an auto-completion and line editing for free.  Check out the documentation:
http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html